# Killing a forked Windows process in Perl

Tags: windows, multithreading, perl, fork, kill

I'd like to spawn a process, do something and kill it afterwards manually when I'm done.

It's not working though. The process starts, I see the pid and the while loop keeps running until I kill it.

Could it be, that Perl spawns a new shell which then spawns the UI process, which doesn't get killed by Perl when the shell (which Perl spawned) is killed?

```
my $cmd = "notepad.exe";
my $sleepTime = 10;#60 * 10;

$childPid = fork(); 
if ($childPid)
{ # Parent
  print "Started child process id: $childPid\n";
  sleep $sleepTime;

  $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
  while (kill(15, $childPid))
  {
    my $numKilled = kill(SIGTERM, $childPid);
    printf("numKilled: %s\n", $numKilled);
    printf("numKilled: %s\n", $childPid);
    sleep 1;
  }
}

elsif ($childPid == 0)
{ # Child
  system($cmd);
  exit 0;  # will never get here
}
else
{ # Unable to fork
  die "ERROR: Could not fork new process: $!\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Given that your child process is `notepad.exe`, I'm guessing you're on Windows. If so, you might want to explicitly mention that, since process management on Windows can be a bit different than in the *nix environments stereotypically associated with Perl.

Comment: If `$childPid` is `undef` then `$childPid == 0` will evaluate to *true* and cause a `Use of uninitialized value $childPid in numeric eq (==)` warning if you have warnings enabled. That means the final `else` clause will never be executed. You should use `elsif ( defined $childPid )` instead.

Comment: `fork` and signals are both unix concepts that are emulated by Perl on Windows. This is probably not the best approach. Have you considered using Win32::Process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Forks::Super`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super) module provides many useful facilities for handling forked processes, as well as offering a more portable interface.

This program runs `notepad` to edit the program's own source file and kills the child process after five seconds. If you need to pass parameters to the command then you should specify it as an anonymous array of values like this. If you use a single string like `cmd => qq<notepad "$0">` instead then you will start a copy of cmd.exe which in turn starts notepad.exe, and the `kill` command will just leave notepad running as an orphan

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Forks::Super;

if ( my $pid = fork({ cmd => [ 'notepad', $0 ] }) ) {
  sleep 5;
  Forks::Super::kill('TERM', $pid);
  print "Killed\n";
}
```

Note that if you want to apply a timeout to the child process then you can write

```
my $pid = fork({ cmd => 'notepad', timeout => 600 })
```